# Ignore subsequent delimiters when parsing a string

Tags: windows, batch-file

with the code below, I'm trying to get ProjName to read:

"word1 word2 - word3"

However the output I'm getting is:

"word1 word2"

How can I ignore subsequent instances of the delimiter?

```
@echo

SET FolderName="100 - word1 word2 - word3"

for /F "tokens=2* delims=-" %%i IN (%FolderName%) DO (set ProjName=%%i)

echo %ProjName%

pause
```

Many thanks.

EDIT - just to add, the 'words' could also be numbers.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect. You shown what you currently get, but what do you want?

Comment: Hi Jeb, thanks for commenting - the second line of my question stated the result I wanted.  Dennis' answer as solved it perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, after rereading it, it's obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET FolderName="100 - word1 word2 - word3"
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=-" %%a IN (%FolderName%) DO (set ProjName=%%b)
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("%ProjName%") do set ProjName=%%a

echo %ProjName%

pause
```

This works because of the tokens. a in this case is the first token, so everything before -, and b = *, so everything else.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis, that nailed it - I'm not quite sure how it works though with the '%%a' and '%%b' , i thought these were just arbitrary variable names - how does %%b equate to the desired value?  Perhaps I need to do more reading!

Comment: BTW, I have updated my answer to get rid of the leading space

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and update Dennis, very much appreciated.